# C++ Point to an object and then move its memory position

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm using C++14. Let's assume I have a `class X` and a `std::vector<X> mVector`.

I also have the following code:

```
std::shared_ptr<X> AddX(const X &x)
{
    mVector.push_back[x];
    return std::shared_ptr<X>(&mVector[mVector.size()-1])
}
```

This method inserts the object `x` into `mVector` and returns me a shared pointer to this inserted object.

```
X x1;
shared_ptr<X> pX1 = AddX(x1);
```

Everything works fine, but when I insert a second object

```
X x2;
shared_ptr<X> pX2 = AddX(x2);
```

`pX1` doesn't point to the inserted object `x1`, because the last push_back has moved its position in memory (seen after hard debug). This is a pity for me, because my program needs these pointers to work correctly, and `mVector` needs to be dynamic, it's being all the time modified (with new `X` objects, or old ones are deleted).

How can I fix this? I guess than a way could be working with the objects indices instead of their pointers, but this would penalize my execution time because I should update many attributes every time I modify `mVector`. Is there a posibility to manage it and still working with pointers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First things first. `Everything works fine`. No. Nothing works fine. You should not return a shared pointer (or any other smart pointer for this matter) to the memory which you didn't allocate yourself.

Vector manages its own members, and if you try to manage `vector` elements, you are in for a big trouble.

Now to your question. Looks like `vector` is not a good container for your goal. Provided you use normal pointer (rather than the smart one) you can use, for example, `std::deque` - as long as you do not insert in the middle of the queue, and only use `push_back` and `push_front`.

Another option would be to use indices instead of the pointers and keep `vector` around - indices will remain the same even after insertions.

Comment: A type wrapping "reference to vector" and "index", which has a conversion or operators *, -> to "reference to contained type" would be a way of making a pointer-esque thing for your second option

Comment: @Caleth, I do not see any reason to add an extra pointer-looking layer on top of a simple index. This could only confuse code users.

Comment: So that the other code doesn't know about the vector. The type I described is approximately `vector::iterator`